# Using raster calculator with GDAL in Python to make sum?

Tags: python, gdal, raster-calculator

I have 130 rasters in a folder and I would like to create a new raster containing the sum of the 130 raster cell values.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can us `gdal_calc.py` in a for loop. First read all the files name, then use:

`gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif -B input2.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B"`

And then in a loop:

`gdal_calc.py -A inputX.tif -B result.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B"`

Where `inputX.tif`is the current file you are looping over, so your loop should start at `input3` since the first two have already been summed to create `result.tif`.